# Terms of use for Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have logged into my Facebook account on a computer where my Facebook application is running. Can I send/receive data(like friends, like etc.) from this application to/from a different device on which I am not logged into my Facebook account?

Answer (score 2):

offline access is deprecated, facebook is giving away 60 day access token instead. You can read about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `offline_access` permission, you may access the data at any time and from any machine.